# Being able to change your profile picture and bio from the app

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, ios-app, profile-picture

This is probably something that's been asked before, but it'd be a major convenience if a person would be able to change their profile settings like your picture and bio from the app.  If you don't have a computer on you at the time and you feel you need to change something, it'd be nice if you'd just be able to do it in the app.

Comment: You can change everything using a browser on any mobile device. (browse the site, choose "full site" and you can then edit)